# Apply more than 1 ID to an image

Tags: html, css

I want to add an image of Ireland to my website. Ireland is made up of 32 counties; what I want to do is allow the user to click on a county, which will bring them to a more detailed page about that county. Also, the appearance of that county will change on hover.

To accomplish this, I'd like to have multiple IDs for the same element. Is this possible?

Comment: You may want to use something like Image Maps for this (google it up)

Comment: How is this related to multiple id (that is forbidden) for the same element ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios - you mean impossible, not forbidden.

Comment: can an image be split up and then given a seperate id. If this is possible I will be able to solve the rest. I have looked at coordinates, but the shapes of the counties will not allow this

Comment: @vsync: it *is* possible. You actually *can* put the same id twice... just don't expect it to work ;) But you're right, forbidden is not the most appropriate word: "that is an error" would fit better :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios - he said more than one to the same element, not multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: @vsync you're totally right, and that's even worse :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a question, but why not simply use a class in conjunction with an id???

`<img src="#" id="firstID" class="thisImage">`

Then simply use `#firstID.thisImage` or `#firstID`, or `.thisImage` to select the image.

Comment: The question is at the top of the page.

Comment: @Liam thanks. It wasn't there when first posed. It was *edited* to add a question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use an ID for this, as IDs are unique and are to be used to indicate one object.

Instead, try using classes separated by spaces:

```
<div class="county ireland" id="mayo"></div>
<div class="county ireland" id="clare"></div>
```

Then, you can refer to them like this:

```
#mayo {
    /* Styling for a specific div */
}

.county {
    /* Styling for all county divs */
}

.ireland {
    /* Styling for Ireland counties */
}

.county: hover {
    /* Styling when counties are hovered over */
}
```

Comment: How do I give county Mayo on the map the id of mayo. Mayo and Clare are part of the image which can only have one id, I do understand the css you have given.

Comment: @Liam `<div id="map"><div class="county" id="mayo"></div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one `id` per element. What you describe as a goal suggests that you can use a client-side image map, implemented using a `map` element with `area` elements specifying areas in an image and associated URLs. For a geographic map, you probably want to use some image map utility that lets you specify the areas graphically and generates the markup for you (which looks messy, since the counties would need to be specified by the coordinates of the vertexes of a polygon).

There is no direct way to change an area of an image map on mouseover. You would need to use a graphics program to generate 32 versions of the image, each with one county highlighted, and change the entire image when one of the areas is highlighted.